# How to receive the multiple rows of json object from php in android activity?

Tags: php, android, json, android-intent

This is my json

```
 {"user_data":[{"year":"2017","month":"12","day":"12","StartTime":"2:00 am","Endtime":"4:00 am","Hours":"02:00:00"},{"year":"2018","month":"12","day":"10","StartTime":"5:00 am","Endtime":"7:00 am","Hours":"02:00:00"}]}
```

The json object i received using fetch.php code

```
    <?php
require "init.php";

   //$name = $_POST["name"];
  // $password = $_POST["password"];

 $name = "surya";
  $password = "1995";

        $Sql = "SELECT * FROM `user_info` 
        WHERE `name`='".$name."' AND 
        `password`='".$password."';";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $Sql);
    $retrive = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
        $user_id =  $row['id']; 
        $sql = "SELECT id, ScheduleDate, StartTime,Endtime, Hours,Employeeid 
        FROM empdet WHERE Employeeid ='".$user_id."' ";
        $result = $con->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            $id=$row["id"]. 
            $date=$row["ScheduleDate"]; 
            $start=$row["StartTime"]; 
            $end=$row["Endtime"];
            $hour=$row["Hours"];
            $Employeeid=$row["Employeeid"];
            list($year,$month,$day) = split("-",$date);
            $data[] = array("year"=>$year,
                            "month"=>$month,
                            "day"=>$day,
                            "StartTime"=>$start,
                            "Endtime"=>$end,
                            "Hours"=>$hour );   
        }$response = $data;
    } else 
        {
            echo "0 results";
        }
}
echo json_encode(array("user_data"=> $response)); 
?>
```

my question is how to receive multiple rows of json object in android activity,
first i tried to receive one row it worked ,but when i tried to set a loop it is not working in android activity,and also i need send the multiple rows in intent to next activity.i tried diffrent ways but i cannot find it how to set loop .

1.how to receiving the multiple rows of json object data from php file
2.how to set a loop in intent to send the multiple rows one by one
3.how to receive them in next activity using loop
please anyone help me to do it!!

this is my android code!
MAinactivity

```
        package com.example.myapplication;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;


    public class Login extends Activity
    {
        EditText name, password;
        String NAME=null, PASSWORD=null, EMAIL=null;
        String Name, Password;
        Context ctx=this;
        String year,month,day,StartTime,Endtime,Hours;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
            name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_name);
            password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_password);
        }
        public void main_login(View v)
        {
            Name = name.getText().toString();
            Password = password.getText().toString();
            BackGround b = new BackGround();
            b.execute(Name, Password);
        }

        class BackGround extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
        {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params)
            {
                String name = params[0];
                String password = params[1];
                String data="";
                int tmp;
               // creating the connection with localhost
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://localhost/sample/loo/login.php");
                    String urlParams = "name="+name+"&password="+password;
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                    os.write(urlParams.getBytes());
                    os.flush();
                    os.close();
                    InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    while((tmp=is.read())!=-1)
                    {
                        data+= (char)tmp;
                    }
                    is.close();
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                    return data;
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
                }
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result)
            {
                String err=null;
                //fetching thte data from database using php/json

                for (int j = 0; j < result.length(); j++) {

                    try
                    {

                        JSONObject root = new JSONObject(result);

                        boolean error = root.getBoolean("error");

                        if (!error) {

                            JSONObject user_data = root.getJSONObject("user_data");
                            year  = user_data.getString("year");
                            month  = user_data.getString("month");
                            day  = user_data.getString("day");
                            StartTime  = user_data.getString("StartTime");
                            Endtime  = user_data.getString("Endtime");
                            Hours  = user_data.getString("Hours");

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        err = "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
                    }        }
                //passing the value to calender activity
  Intent i = new Intent(ctx, Calender.class);
                            i.putExtra("year", year);
                            i.putExtra("month", month);
                            i.putExtra("day", day);
                            i.putExtra("StartTime", StartTime);
                            i.putExtra("Endtime", Endtime);
                            i.putExtra("Hours", Hours);
                            i.putExtra("err", err);
                            startActivity(i);

                if(result==null)
                {
                 Toast.makeText(Login.this, "result is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                //else {
                //   Intent i = new Intent(ctx, Main2Activity.class);
                //  startActivity(i);
                //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "has a value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // }

            }
        }
    }
```

This is my second activity

```
    package com.example.myapplication;
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.CalendarContract;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Calender extends AppCompatActivity
{
    String day, month, year,Hours,Endtime,StartTime, Err,Shours,Sminutes,Ssecond,Ehours,Eminutes,Esecond,Eampm,Sampm;
    int s,mo;
    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_CALENDAR = 123;
    Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calender);
        context = Calender.this;
        writeCalendarEvent();

    }
    private void writeCalendarEvent()
    {

        year = getIntent().getStringExtra("year");
        month = getIntent().getStringExtra("month");
        day = getIntent().getStringExtra("day");
        StartTime = getIntent().getStringExtra("StartTime");
        Endtime = getIntent().getStringExtra("Endtime");
        Hours = getIntent().getStringExtra("Hours");
        Err = getIntent().getStringExtra("err");

}
}
```

Comment: I always wonder why people provide us with screenshot of textual output? You can just copy&paste...

Comment: s,i am in confused state, i forget i can do that!

Comment: Please paste your `JSON' String instead of Screen short

Comment: @Shailesh i have edited!

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
try
{
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject(result);

        JSONArray user_data = root.getJSONArray("user_data");

        for (int i = 0; i < user_data.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jsonObject = user_data.getJSONObject(i);

            year  = jsonObject.getString("year");
            month  = jsonObject.getString("month");
            day  = jsonObject.getString("day");
            StartTime  = jsonObject.getString("StartTime");
            Endtime  = jsonObject.getString("Endtime");
            Hours  = jsonObject.getString("Hours");


        }
} 
catch (JSONException e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: this code is working,but when i tried to put them in toast it shows 2nd row details,
but i need all the rows,and send them to next activity using intent.is there is any way to do that?

Comment: @selvasurya yes you can pass this data in intent.putextra  and get next activity easily. if you have any face problem tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
JSONArray jArr = root.getJSONArray("user_data");
int arrLen = jArr.length();
if(arrLen != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrLen; i++) 
        {
        JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) jArr.get(i);
        year  = obj.getString("year");
        month  = obj.getString("month");
        day  = obj.getString("day");
        StartTime  = obj.getString("StartTime");
        Endtime  = obj.getString("Endtime");
        Hours  = obj.getString("Hours");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

from json screenshot your `user_data` is not `JSONObject` actually this is `JSONArray` so check below code

```
  JASONArray jsonArray = root.getJSONArray("user_data");
  JSONObject user_data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
  year  = user_data.getString("year");
  month  = user_data.getString("month");
  day  = user_data.getString("day");
  StartTime  = user_data.getString("StartTime");
  Endtime  = user_data.getString("Endtime");
  Hours  = user_data.getString("Hours");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. This is just parsing only for sending data from one activity to another activity you need to store that data to on array an send it on Intent and receive that data to another activity.

```
try
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray userData = jsonObject.getJSONArray("user_data");

            if (userData != null)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < userData.length(); j++) {

                    JSONObject user_data = userData.getJSONObject(j);
                    year = user_data.getString("year");
                    month = user_data.getString("month");
                    day = user_data.getString("day");
                    StartTime = user_data.getString("StartTime");
                    Endtime = user_data.getString("Endtime");
                    Hours = user_data.getString("Hours");
                    // here store this String value in one array and pass that array in Intent
                }
            }

            //like your array name is UserData then you can do like this 
            // but make sure if you use List with Model then make it 
            //Serializable or Parcelable
            if (UserData != null)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(ctx, Main2Activity.class);
                i.putExtra("userData", UserData);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else{
              // data is null or something wrong
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: sir,i have dout in this,there are two rows in db,so the for loop will be executed for 2 times right!,when the for loop executs its first loop,weather it will send the data of first loop in indent,after that 2nd time loop executed,and the indent will send the data of second loop?which means one row after another row?

Comment: for loop executed for two times and the indent is used for two times to send the two rows seperately

Comment: If you start an activity for every row you will end up with two activities. That does not look good.

Comment: You better send the whole json text to the activity with `intent.putExtra("result", result);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it will work

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
        String user = jsonObject.getString("user_data");
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(user);
        for(int j =0 ; j<jsonArray.length() ; j++) {
            JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
            String year = json.getString("year");
            String month = json.getString("month");
            String day = json.getString("day"):


        }
```